# function keep return null value instead of an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a function that either return me a list of item or a message display what kind of problem my data is having. I have set condition for when it's null but instead of return the error message, it keep display nothing.

My code :

```
public List<Device> GetDeviceFromRoom(int? roomID)
{
    return this.dbContext.Set<Device>().Where(x => x.RoomDevice.Any(b => b.RoomId == roomID)).ToList();
}

public List<Room> GetRoomFromLocation(int locationID)
{
    return this.dbContext.Set<Room>().Where(x => x.LocationId == locationID).ToList();
}

var roomList = roomRepository.GetRoomFromLocation(locationID);
if (roomList == null)
{
    throw new BaseException(ErrorMessages.LOCATION_DEVICE_EMPTY);
}
else
{        
    var deviceList = new List<Device>();
    for (int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
    {
        var roomAt = roomList.ElementAt(i);
        var deviceListAt = deviceRepository.GetDeviceFromRoom(roomAt.RoomId);
        deviceList.AddRange(deviceListAt);
    }
    if (deviceList != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceList.Count; i++)
        {
            var deviceElement = deviceList.ElementAt(i);
            var deviceElementModel = deviceElement.ToViewModel<DeviceViewModel>();
            result.Add(deviceElementModel);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new BaseException(ErrorMessages.LOCATION_DEVICE_EMPTY);
    }
}
```

My result :

```
[]
```

Comment: `[]` isn't null FYI. It's a JSON representation of an empty array.

Comment: What's the problem? If the queries return no results, the JSON document will contain an empty array

Comment: BTW `deviceList != null` will always be true. The list may be empty, but isn't null. The way this code is written, it will return an empty `result` array if there are no results

Comment: You seem to be conflating `null` and empty. `List<Device> deviceList = null;` <-- this is `null`. `List<Device> deviceList = new List<Device>();` <-- this is not null, but it is an empty list.

Comment: [What does a null object mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598108/what-does-a-null-object-mean)

Comment: `roomList` will never be null either. Frankly, why all this "repository" methods? Why not create just *one* LINQ query that loads the desired data from the database using the configured entities, properties and relations? Eg `myContext.Devices.Where(dev=>dev.Room.Location=locationId)` ? This will execute a single query to return all devices, while the current code, if it worked, would execute `1 + M*N` queries